# Select Label by Input type

Tags: css, css-selectors, label

Is there a way to exclude or select Label by input types, something similar to input field?

```
label:not([type=checkbox])
label[type=checkbox]
```

Comment: Whats your question actually? do u want to know what are the other input types... could not understand clearly.. rephrase...

Comment: The second one definitely works. The `[attribute=value]` css selector works for anything, not just an input. (you could get class names, if it is disabled etc) This may not work in some older versions of IE though. I have not seen the :not selector before though so I cannot comment on it.

Comment: @Vinay question is, how to select or exclude label for input fieldtype=checkbox, in CSS?

Comment: Oh wait, do you want to target the label based on the `for` attribute of it? I think I misunderstood your original question.

Comment: @TheWaxMann yep, that's the question :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you give your checkboxes specific id's that all start with the same thing, you could do the following:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTerms" />
<label for="chkTerms">Read terms & conditions</label>
```

CSS

```
label[for*="chk"], label[htmlfor*="chk"]
{
css here
}
```

Probably modern browsers only though.
EDIT: I have just tried a fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AZpfU/3/) and it works in chrome and IE 8 & 9 but not 7. I did not try it in FF.

EDIT2: Just to give an explanation of what is going on here, the square brackets looks for an attribute called for. The the asterix changes the behaviour of the equals from just a plain equals, to mean contains - wherever the for attribute contains "chk" it will apply that style. You can replace the * with a ^ and it will change it to mean starts with instead of contains.

EDIT3: BoltClock has provided a fix for IE7 in a comment, I have updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Yeah, IE7 has trouble with attribute selectors, and `for` is a famous example where you need to use `htmlFor` instead.

Comment: @BoltClock I was unaware of the htmlfor selector. Thanks :-) I will update my post to include that to fix IE7.

Answer (score 5):

How about `input[type=checkbox] + label { /*label style here*/ }` ? It might work if text is just after the input element. I have not tested that.

Comment: Can you modify the html? You could for example add class for those labels. Or use jQuery to go trough all labels and check which kind input those have.

Comment: And if the label is before the input, then you could just modify html code so that label is after ther input and then modify css to position label before the input.

Comment: yea this can be solution, then `text-indent:-100px` to move it in front of checkbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use your checkbox with basic data-attribute reference..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-0" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-0">Whatever</label>
```

If you not expect this... let us know...

Comment: I know I can use id or class, I asked if would be possible to do it other way, without using `label {style}` then overwrite it with `#checkbox-0 {style}`