# CSS - Selector of label for type?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599627/how-to-select-label-for-email-in-css) explaining how to add a selector of a label for a given element. However, I'd like to use it to select all labels for a given type (specifically, the type radio). Trying:

```
label[for=input[type="radio"]] {
    /* Styles */
}
```

and

```
label[for=[type="radio"]] {
    /* Styles */
}
```

does not work and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to do it right. Can someone explain the solution to me? Thank you much!

Comment: Could you share your html. Cause I believe it should be ( label input[type="radio"] ) a jsfiddle would help tremendously.

Comment: I would do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/Ag3pt/

Comment: [This][1] probably answers you're question.




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031926/select-label-by-input-type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're wanting can't be done using current CSS3 selectors.

There are plans for this feature to be included in CSS level 4 selectors, but the spec for this is not yet finalised, and certainly not implemented in any current browsers.

The idea is for a selector that would look something like this:

```
label /for/ [type="radio"] {
    /* styles */
}
```

But that's for the future, not for now. Sorry.

You can read about it here: http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/reference-combination/

In the meanwhile, if you need this kind of thing, you will need to make sure you structure your HTML such that the elements can reference each other using current CSS selectors.

For example, if they're next to each other, you could use this:

```
label + input[type="radio"] { .... }
```

That's as close as you'll get for the time being.

Comment: Both of your selectors match the input, not the label. Also, the reference combinator may not be usable in CSS if it remains excluded from the fast Selectors 4 profile that is to be used in CSS.

Answer (score 4):

You should use special classes for those labels instead. You cannot style a parent element based on its children's atttributes in CSS [presently].

```
<label class='radio'><input type='radio'></label>
```

Your stylesheet would say

```
label.radio{
  /* add styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**First - a correction**

The `for` attribute [is only to be tied to an `id` of the form element it is associated with](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label), so you are misusing the attribute for what you are seeking to do. The design of `for` is to tie it to *one specific element* in the form. So something like this:

```
<label for="RadioChk">My Radio Button</label><input id="RadioChk" type="radio" />
```

So the `for` is not the solution to just checking for a `type`.

**Second - the only CSS only solution**

The only clean way it can be done with pure CSS is if your elements are ordered like so (`label` *following* the `input`):

```
<input type="radio" /><label>My Radio Button</label>
```

Which then allows [this css to select](http://jsfiddle.net/SYB24/3/):

```
input[type=radio] + label {
    /* styles */
}
```

If that cannot be done, then I would go with AbsoluteƵERØ's solution of using a class.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible (with CSS alone anyway).  The `[attribute=value]` syntax works by checking the value of the attribute for that specific element.  Thus, `for=[type="radio"]]` is looking for something like `<label for='[type="radio"]'>` (if the syntax is even valid).

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks though.

Comment: `[for=[type="radio"]]` is not valid - the value has to be quoted `[for='[type="radio"]']` or escaped `[for=\[type=\"radio\"\]]` for it to be valid. (Note that the Jigsaw validator chokes on the escaped version but it is valid by spec.)

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
input[type=radio]
{
CSS goes here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you may have misunderstood my question. I'm looking to select the "label" for a "radio" element, not the "radio" element itself.

Comment: Yep, just realized I misunderstood. Sorry.